# How to split a file which is delimited by bullet points

Tags: python, mysql, bash

I'm trying to split a large file that has several paragraphs, each one is of variable length and the only delimiter would be the bullet point for the next paragraph...

Is there a way to get several different files with each individual paragraph? 
The final thing is to write each individual paragraph to a MySQL DB...

example input:

- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
- Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

output: each paragraph is a separate entry in the DB

Comment: Can you provide example input and output files?

Comment: By bullet point what are you trying to say .you could use .split("the character you want to delimit here")

Comment: this not plain text ?

Comment: Is this a plain text

Comment: Do you have db with only one column

Comment: no there are various columns in the DB, but i will adapt them to the script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is how you split your file by bullet point:

```py
new_files = open(source_file).read().split(u'\u2022')
for par in new_files:
  open("%s.txt"%new_files.index(par),"w").write("%s"%par) 
  LOAD DATA INFILE "%s.txt"%new_files.index(par) INTO TABLE your_DB_name.your_table;
```

Comment: Perfect! And how may i inject the output to the MySQL DB as a separate entry

Comment: do you want to insert the new files as .txt or the paragraphs as strings?

Comment: paragraphs as strings, there is a small error " Unicode decode error: ascii codec can not decode byte.... ordinal not in range (128)

Comment: sorry, I mean try to add **encode('utf-8')** this way `open("%s.txt"%new_files.index(par),"w").write("%s"%par.encode('utf-8')))`

Comment: @Did thanks for accepting the answer if this was helpful for you

Comment: thank you very much! it was.. the only trick @ the end was to discover the 'separating' character :)

Answer (score 0):

This conects to mysql DB and reads the file and splits it at each bullet point and inserts the data into mysql DB table

***My Code:***

```
#Server Connection to MySQL:

import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host= "localhost",
              user="root",
              passwd="newpassword",
              db="db")
x = conn.cursor()

try:
    file_data = open("FILE_NAME_WITH_EXTENSION").read().split(u'\u2022')
    for text in file_data:
        print text
        x.execute("""INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES (%s)""",(text))
        conn.commit()
except:
    conn.rollback()

conn.close()
```